# How do I get rid of geom_smooth continuous error code?

Tags: r, forecasting

Here is code:

```
ggplot(exchangeGBP) + aes(Date, `GBP/EUR`) + geom_line(color = "deepskyblue") +
 geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Error Code:

```
`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

Comment: That's not an error, just a message to let you know that the formula is being set to a default. The code still runs, right?

Comment: Yes, the code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not seeing an error. R has three different types of what are called *conditions*: errors, warnings, and messages. Here's how they're described in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html) by Hadley Wickham (an excellent book for learning more about R):

> Fatal **errors** are raised by stop() and force all execution to
> terminate. Errors are used when there is no way for a function to
> continue.

> **Warnings** are generated by warning() and are used to
> display potential problems, such as when some elements of a vectorised
> input are invalid, like log(-1:2).

> **Messages** are generated by
> message() and are used to give informative output in a way that can
> easily be suppressed by the user (?suppressMessages()). I often use
> messages to let the user know what value the function has chosen for
> an important missing argument.

Hadley also wrote the ggplot2 package, and his last sentence describes what's happening. What you're seeing is a message that's telling you what formula the function picked.

Before I get to the solutions, let's create a reproducible example.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_smooth()
#`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

There are two ways to stop the message from appearing. You could suppress the message from appearing as suggested in the book excerpt. But the better approach is to replace the missing value. In my example, both *method* and *formula* are missing. You can copy and paste the values from the message.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'loess', formula = 'y ~ x')
```

Your example would look like this.

```
ggplot(exchangeGBP) + aes(Date, `GBP/EUR`) + geom_line(color = "deepskyblue") +
 geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = 'y ~ x')
```

No more message!

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at the book.

Comment: It's a good read. Hadley also wrote the book R for Data Science, which is also great.